# Showing that for every acute angle $x$ in a right triangle $\frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\cos x}\ge 2\sqrt 2$ is always true

Tags: inequality, trigonometry

The problem is to show that in a right-angle triangle with hypothenuse K and sides M and N, the inequality $\frac{K}{M}+\frac{K}{N}\ge 2\sqrt 2$ is always true.

**My approach:** I tried to simplify the expression $\frac{K}{M}+\frac{K}{N}$=$\frac{K(M+N)}{MN}$, and since we have a triangle, this means that $K\ge M+N$ which makes us conclude that $$\frac{K(M+N)}{MN}\ge\frac{K^2}{MN}$$, and since K is the hypothenuse, we get:$\frac{K(M+N)}{MN}\ge \frac{M^2+N^2}{MN}\ge 2$ by AM-GM. So this means that I got: $$\frac{K}{M}+\frac{K}{N}\ge 2$$ but couldn't reach the desired result which is $2\sqrt 2$, so any help or another approach is much appreciated.

Comment: This strikes me as a run-of-the-mill optimization problem. Since the function f(x)  in question approaches infinity as x —> 0+ and as x —> π/2-, it is necessary only to find where the derivative vanishes and to show that this is a local minimum, and then evaluate f(x) at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can note that:

$$\frac{K}{M} + \frac{K}{N} = \frac{K(M+N)}{MN} = \frac{\sqrt{M^2+N^2}(M+N)}{MN}\geq \frac{\sqrt{2MN}\cdot 2\sqrt{MN}}{MN} = 2\sqrt{2}$$

where it has been used the classic inequality: $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}: a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$.

Answer (score 4):

**IDEA 1:**

Using AM–GM inequality:
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\cos x}}{2}\ge \sqrt{\frac{1}{\sin x}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos x}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{2\sin x\cos x}}=\sqrt{2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin 2x}}
$$
We know that $0< \sin 2x\le 1$, given that $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin 2x}}\ge 1$. Thus
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\cos x}}{2}\ge \sqrt{2}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\cos x}\ge 2\sqrt 2.
$$

Suppose we have a triangle
[image]

then
$$
\frac{K}{M}+\frac{K}{N}=\frac{1}{\frac{M}{K}}+\frac{1}{\frac{N}{K}}=\frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\cos x}\ge 2\sqrt 2.
$$

**IDEA 2:**

Using AM–GM inequality and $x+\frac{1}{x}\ge 2$ for all $x>0$.
$$
\frac{\frac{K}{M}+\frac{K}{N}}{2}\ge \sqrt{\frac{K}{M}\cdot \frac{K}{N}}=\sqrt{\frac{K^2}{MN}}=\sqrt{\frac{M^2+N^2}{MN}}=\sqrt{\frac{M}{N}+\frac{N}{M}}\ge \sqrt 2\Rightarrow \frac{K}{M}+\frac{K}{N}\ge 2\sqrt 2.
$$

Comment: I didn't think of using the AM-GM inequality this way, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Using [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure):
$$(\sin^2x + \cos^2x)\left(\frac1{\sin x}+\frac1{\cos x}\right)^2\geqslant (1+1)^3$$

Comment: I don't know anything about this inequality, I think you could approach the problem using some basic math,as it was given asa middle school challenge

Comment: Oh, best to clarify that requirement in the question itself then.  Added another way using basic algebra and trigonometry in a separate post.

Comment: @Macavity: Nice Idea but a question: for the case of $\frac 1p +\frac 1q=1$ you take $p=\frac {1}{\sin^2 x}$and like that for cosine ?

Comment: @Khosrotash Well, $p=3, q = 3/2$ here.

Answer (score 2):

Just another way:
$$\left(\frac1{\sin x}+\frac1{\cos x} \right)^2=\frac{\sin^2x+\cos^2x+2\cdot\sin x\cdot\cos x}{\sin^2x \cdot \cos^2x}=\frac1{\frac14\sin^2 2x}+\frac2{\frac12\sin 2x} \\ \geqslant4+4$$

Comment: FYI, I was just in the process of adding to my answer the same basic approach as in your answer, when I saw that you had posted your answer, so I just cancelled my edit as I didn't want to duplicate what you've shown.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Your original approach seems more elementary anyway, while the above is short, not sure if the OP is familiar with $\sin 2x$ expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Using the QM-HM inequality:

$$
\sqrt{
\frac{\sin^{2}(x)+\cos^{2}(x)}{2}
}
\geq
\frac{2}{
\frac{1}{\sin(x)}+
\frac{1}{\cos(x)}
}
$$

and using $\sin^{2}(x)+\cos^{2}(x)=1$, we get what we want:

$$
\frac{1}{\sin(x)}+
\frac{1}{\cos(x)}
\geq2\sqrt{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using that $K^2 = M^2 + N^2$ by the Pythagorean theorem, that for all positive $x$ we have $x + \frac{1}{x} \ge 2$ by the [AM–GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM%E2%80%93GM_inequality) (or, alternatively, from $(x-1)^2\ge 0 \;\to\; x^2-2x+1\ge 0\;\to\;x^2+1\ge 2x\;\to\; x+\frac{1}{x}\ge 2$), and your LHS expression simplification, we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{K^2(M+N)^2}{M^{2}N^{2}} & = \frac{(M^2+N^2)(M^2+2MN+N^2)}{M^{2}N^{2}} \\
& = \frac{M^2+2MN+N^2}{N^{2}} + \frac{M^2+2MN+N^2}{M^{2}} \\
& = \frac{M^2}{N^2} + 2\left(\frac{M}{N}\right) + 1 + 1 + 2\left(\frac{N}{M}\right) + \frac{N^2}{M^2} \\
& = 2 + 2\left(\frac{M}{N} + \frac{1}{\frac{M}{N}}\right) + \left(\frac{M^2}{N^2} + \frac{1}{\frac{M^2}{N^2}}\right) \\
& \ge 2 + 2(2) + 2 \\
& = 8
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Since $M$, $N$ and $K$ are all positive, taking square roots of both sides gives the requested inequality, i.e.,

$$\frac{K}{M}+\frac{K}{N}\ge 2\sqrt{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

$$f(x)=\csc x+\sec x\implies f’(x)=-\csc x \cot x+\sec x\tan x=0$$
$$\implies \tan^3x=1\implies x=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Can you finish?

Comment: OP mentions that they only know middle school math in a comment to a separate answer. I doubt if they have any clue of calculus.